# how to map a dataframe and vectors into function parameters with *pply functions

Tags: r, apply, mapply

The problem I met is specific operation for *pply(like apply or mapply, etc, I'm not sure).

The dataframe is `dlt`:

```
        dlt.1    dlt.2    dlt.3    dlt.4    dlt.5  
  1  3.244198 6.482869 9.711874 12.92918 16.13489
  6  3.196401 6.391871 9.585553 12.77681 15.96547
 19  3.182911 6.365424 9.547196 12.72799 15.90795
 24  3.164079 6.328089 9.491971 12.65577 15.81984
```

and the vector is `freq`:

```
 1 2 3 4 5
```

Now I intend to map the `dt` and `freqn` to a function `foo`:

```
foo <- function( dlti, freqi){ dlti * freqi }
```

where I hope the ith column of `dlt` correspond to the ith element of `freq`

I tried `apply` and `mapply`, but both failed. Would anyone please show me what is correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what you actually want because you don't show the desired result.  Without that, there is ambiguity in your question.

```
    dlt <- tribble(
       ~dlt_1,    ~dlt_2,   ~dlt_3,    ~dlt_4,    ~dlt_5  ,
    3.244198, 6.482869, 9.711874, 12.92918, 16.13489,
    3.196401, 6.391871, 9.585553, 12.77681, 15.96547,
   3.182911, 6.365424, 9.547196, 12.72799, 15.90795,
   3.164079, 6.328089, 9.491971, 12.65577, 15.81984 
)
freqi <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
foo <- function(dlti,freqi){dlti * freqi}
purrr::map2(dlt,freqi,foo)

$dlt_1
[1] 3.244198 3.196401 3.182911 3.164079

$dlt_2
[1] 12.96574 12.78374 12.73085 12.65618

$dlt_3
[1] 29.13562 28.75666 28.64159 28.47591

$dlt_4
[1] 51.71672 51.10724 50.91196 50.62308

$dlt_5
[1] 80.67445 79.82735 79.53975 79.09920
```

Comment: that's my exact intention. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do this by replicating the 'freq' and then do the `*`

```
dlt*freq[col(dlt)]
#     dlt.1    dlt.2    dlt.3    dlt.4    dlt.5
#1  3.244198 12.96574 29.13562 51.71672 80.67445
#6  3.196401 12.78374 28.75666 51.10724 79.82735
#19 3.182911 12.73085 28.64159 50.91196 79.53975
#24 3.164079 12.65618 28.47591 50.62308 79.09920
```

---

Or using `Map` in `base R`

```
dlt[] <-  Map(`*`, dlt, freq)
```

Comment: your answer is also highly appreciated for its concise.